# Standards for non-bearing wall construction in a carport?

Tags: walls, framing

I purchased a SteelMaster metal building, and hired a contractor to assemble and install it and construct wood end-walls.
I don't know much about this stuff, but I was pretty underwhelmed by the wall construction:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is this appropriate construction? And if not, are there standards I can reference and have the contractor target instead?

Comment: Are the 2x4s attached(screwed/bolted) to the building?  It might not be the neatest job, but it would depend if it just holding up sliding or a feature in a home.

Comment: 2x4s do not bend well, the contractor probably did the job with the idea of the least waste of material.  Could have the job been done neater, yes, but the cost would probably have gone up quite a bit for just looks, that probably will be covered up.  If the wall falls over just by you leaning on it, then you have something to complain about.

Comment: Thanks! When the post was edited to remove the link to an imgur album in favor of inlining the image, most of the images were omitted and only a single image was kept. I've updated the post to include the other images, too.

Comment: Think your contractor did a decent job.  Imagine the building manufacturer has an expensive end wall option that would look better.

Comment: Yeah, the building manufacturer has metal end walls for the building that are about $4K apiece, which is what I'm trying to avoid. The 2x4's aren't currently attached to the building, but the contractor assures me they will be. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The Code allows interior non-load bearing wall construction and they call it a “Partition”.

A “Partition” is defined as dividing “portions of stores, offices or similar places occupied by one tenant and does not form a corridor serving an occupant load of less than 30.” (See Section 603.1.8)

There are no minimum requirements for size, spacing, etc. for Partitions.

Note to original answer:
Oops, I’m confused, are you?

First, I just realized that wall is not non-load bearing. According to the definition of non-load bearing in the code, your wall is not an interior Partition. In fact it has wind, seismic loads, etc. and probably some roof loads. Whew… glad I got that taken care of. All this is found in the International Building Code (IBC) as B put together by the International Code Council (ICC).

All of the sizing and fastening of wood frame construction is located in Chapter 23.

Comment: Thanks! Which Code are you referring to?
Given these are end-walls (i.e., exterior walls) for a building, does that code still apply?

Comment: I would think so, @Dathan. They're entirely non-structural. The car port will stand quite nicely without them. Since all this is doing is (presumably) holding up the exterior siding, it only needs to be strong enough to do that.

Comment: @FreeMan Just because a empty blank wall is in a location where it seems to be non-load bearing, it doesn’t necessarily stay a non-load bearing wall after it is built in an exterior wall location. As soon as it’s built it could transfer wind loads, seismic loads, unless the fasteners were designed somehow as a slip joint.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer to indicate that.